# How to validate string if the first 3 positions are letters

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to validate a string entered by a user. The user must enter a string with 7 characters; the string first 3 characters must be letters and the last 4 must be numbers.

I wrote this piece of code( as a method ) but for some reason it accepts the first character as a number ( which it's suppose to be a letter ) and the rest are numbers. For example :

```
Please enter word : **1gy2345**
```

This will enter the loop, as wanted, and move on into the next method in the main.

If the user enters a word that its length is bigger than 7 it will ask him to enter a valid word.

For example :

```
Please enter word : **bob12345**
The word entered is invalid. Please enter a word beginning with 3 letters and ending with 4 numbers ( The word must be 7 characters long ).
```

Here is my code:

```
public static final String solicitationMessage = " Please enter word ";

    public static final String errorMessage = " The word entered is invalid. Please enter a word beginning with 3 letters and ending with 4 numbers ( The word must be 7 characters long ).

    public static final int lengthOfString = 7;

    public static String validateString(String solicitationMessage, String errorMessage, int lengthOfString) {

        System.out.print(solicitationMessage);

        String word = keyboard.nextLine();

        while (!( word.length() == lengthOfString )) {
            if (((word.charAt(0) <= 'a' || word.charAt(0) >= 'z') || (word.charAt(1) <= 'a' || word.charAt(1) >= 'z')
                    || (word.charAt(2) <= 'a' || word.charAt(2) >= 'z'))) {
                System.out.print(errorMessage);
                System.out.print(solicitationMessage);
                word = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
```

However, if I enter a string higher than the 7 limit character it will ask me again the enter a valid string like it's suppose to do.

The use of regex is not permitted.

Any help ?

Comment: You only enter the loop of length is not 7, so any string of length 7 is considered valid, e.g. `!@#$%^&` would work.

Comment: Also, you might want to change your `<=` comparisons to `<` - since you want `a` and `z` to be considered letters.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy task for regex

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}
```

Some test cases: http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgICi0ZuYCgw/index.html

So it can be something like

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}");
String line;
while(true){
   line= keyboard.nextLine();
   if(pattern.matcher(line).matches()){
     break;
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot use regular expressions.

Comment: @ForzaTekk key information omitted.  Please re-edit your question to explain what is allowed so others don't offer workable, but unacceptable solutions.

Comment: @ForzaTekk Why can't you use regular expressions?  Seems a strange restriction to me.

Comment: we haven't learned it yet in Java. However, I've used regex in another class (computer system administration / management) on Ubuntu.

Comment: *we haven't learned it yet in Java.* So you have learning restrictions and you cannot learn to use the right tool to do the job now?? Strange school.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Use the Character class to test the characters.

```
        if (!(Character.isLetter(word.charAt(0)) &&
             Character.isLetter(word.charAt(1)) &&
             Character.isLetter(word.charAt(2)))) {
                 System.out.print(errorMessage);
                 System.out.print(solicitationMessage);
                 word = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I enter the string as **1hi1234** and it validates it.

Comment: Well the issue here is that the solution is missing a NOT - it prints the error if the validation requirement IS met, rather than if it isn't.

Comment: I was thinking more towards validating the word than catching a bad one.  Mea Culpa.  I fixed the code per **Dawood's** suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment I will only give you the pseudo code. You try to figure out how to implement it :p

```
boolean function validateString(inputString):
    check if inputStrings length is exactly 7:
        if not then return false;
    loop through inputString:
        if the current index is less than 3 and current character is within 'a' - 'z' or within 'A' - 'Z' // check if current character is a letter
           return false;
        else if current index is greater than 2 and current character is not within '0' - '9' // check if current character is not a digit
           return false;
    end loop
    return true
end function
```

Then just call that function in your main method and print necessary error messages.

Answer (score -1):

May be this would help.

```
public static String validateString(String solicitationMessage, String errorMessage, int lengthOfString) {

    System.out.print(solicitationMessage);

    String word = "";
    boolean flag = false;
    while (true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        word = sc.nextLine();
        if(word.length() == lengthOfString){
            for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
                int ascii = (int)word.charAt(i);
                if(i<3 && (ascii > 64 && ascii < 123)){
                    flag = true;
                }else if(i>2 && (ascii > 47 && ascii < 58)){
                    flag = true;
                }else{
                    flag = false;
                    System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                break;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```